# How to design event-driven API with separate packages for server and event handles?

Tags: go

**Background**

I have a **servercore** package which includes **server** struct and all core logic for sending/receiving messages from clients.

The server will operate with different flavours - e.g. EU, USA, AUS. Each flavour has its own set of distinct methods which can be invoked by the clients.

I would like to create separate packages which include (only) those methods. E.g. **euhandles** package.

**The problem**

These methods, in some cases, have to rely on the original **server** methods implemented in **servercore** package.

How can this be designed in golang in an elegant fashion?

**Potential Solutions**

**(1) simply move the methods into separate package - doesn't work**

package euhandles cannot create methods on servercore.Server struct. This is prohibited in Go (can't create methods on third-party structs).

**(2) define functions in separate packages and then simply "register" them - doesn't work**

```
Server.RegisterHandle("someEventName",euhandles.methodFromEu)
```

Problem - methodFromEu function will be unable to access any server methods.

**(3) use embedding:**

```
type serverEU struct { server *servercore.Server }
func (s *serverEU) HandleThat {}

s := new(serverEU)
s.server.registerHandle("someEventName", s.HandleThat)
```

Problem - it becomes a bit cumbersome (extra layer added just to implement a few handles/methods), doesn't seem "clean".

**(4) Dependency Injection**

I just thought of this shortly after posting the question, adding for the sake of comprehensiveness:

```
# in euhandles:
func HandleThat(s *server)

# elsewhere:
s.registerHandle("someEventName", euhandles.HandleThat)

# in servercore:
func (s *server) registerHandle(name string, handleFunc func(*server)) {
  s.handles[name]=func(s *server) { handleFunc(s)}
}
```

Not sure how good/appropriate this is considered to be among Go-programmers.

**Is there any idiomatic, clean way to separate events/handles from the core server?**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is to use embedding, though without the additional indirection:

```
type ServerEU struct {  
   *servercore.Server 
}

s := ServerEU{Server:&baseServer}
s.registerHandle("someEventName", s.HandleThat)
```

Another thing you can try is function pointers in the server:

```
type Server struct {
  // stuff
  LocaleSpecificFunc func(args)
}
```

And in the package:

```
func NewUEServer() *Server {
   s:=Server{//initializers}
   s.LocaleSpecificFunc=func(args) {
      // Here, LocaleSpecificFunc implementation can use s
   }
   return &s
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. Any preference (practicality / correctness / popularity among most used go packages etc.) on your suggested option vs. (4) injection I just added above?

Comment: You can judge practicality once you get at least a skeleton implementation running. If it works, it is correct. I can't talk about popularity. I suggest you pick one that looks reasonable to you and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass `HandleThat` to `registerHandle()` at some point, `HandleThat` is not an integral part of a server. So your DI option (4) makes more sense than embedding actually.

Comment: In that direction, you may want to consider having a server factory.